# Android: Is it possible to have dual sim with different ringtone for receiving call for each sim?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to set different ringtone for each sim card through which the call receiver can identify the sim that receives the call?

Comment: What phone are we talking about? The DSTL1?

Answer (score 0):

Stock Android ROMs don't have support for two SIM cards by default, the ROM in your dual SIM phone is custom made by the manufacturer. So it depends on what phone do you have and if manufacturer put this functionality into the ROM.